# Putting Two dictionary into single

Tags: python

```
Can we get below format using two dictionaries?

    a =  {'a':'b'}
    b =  {'c':'d'}
    l = []
    l.append(a)
    l.append(b)

output would be [{'a':'b'}, {'c':'d'}]

However, Can we put the whole output in a single block like

[{ {'a':'b'}, {'c':'d'} } ]
```

I want to put the list dictionaries in the single block, how I can achieve it ?

Comment: Are you just trying to do output = [{"ITSUS":[a, b]]?

Comment: You need to add what is your underlying need, and what is the code that got you the result you mentioned. The question is not clear to provide any reasonable input.

Comment: [{"ITSUS":[a, b]]? this does not give proper output - [{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}] but expected is [{{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}}]

Comment: Changed the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why you don't just use a regular data frame? Dictionaries can only have one key and one definition. If you wanted you could modify the definition.

A = B + C

However a pandas data frame would be easier and would make more sense.